# Using select statement within an existing Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working an application where I have to use a `select statement` within an `SQL query` using `LINQ`

I have the following SQL Query which has to be converted to LINQ to use in my Controller in my ASP.Net MVC application

**SQL Query**

```
Select * 
From CCUserDataList 
Where CCId IN (
    Select CompanyId 
    From Users 
    Where UserName="test") 
Order by ProductOrder, GradeOrder,TermOrder
```

the above query gives me the results I needed but I am having issues using it in my application where I am using `LINQ` as follows

```
public override IQueryable<CCUserData> Get()
{
    return db.CCUserDataList
        .OrderBy(c => c.ProductOrder)
        .ThenBy(c => c.GradeOrder)
        .ThenBy(c => c.TermOrder);
}
```

And of course above `LINQ` is incomplete if it should return the same results as my SQL query.

May I know the complete LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your class / db structure, I would say you could do :

```
var companyIds = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == "test").Select(u => u.CompanyId);
return db.CCUserDataList.Where(ccu => companyIds.Contains(ccu.CCId)).OrderBy....
```

a join query would probably also work, by the way

or also

```
return db.CCUserDataList
         .Where(ccu => db.Users
                         .Any(u => u.UserName == "test" && ccu.CCId == u.CompanyId));
```

Comment: You mean `var companyIds = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == "test").Select(u => u.CompanyId).ToList();` ?

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak no. I try to stay in an IQueryable world.

Comment: This is how I'd do it also. I wish there was a better way, but if there is, I've yet to find it.